# What are all of the bash metacharacters, exactly?

Tags: bash

I'm writing a program that makes a string safe to use as a string in bash, without further interpretation. Right now, it surrounds the string with `''`s, then replaces every `'` with `'\''`. That works, but now, I also want the resulting strings to look as nice as possible. So, for instance, `sandwich` can be converted to just `sandwich`, but `thing$HOME` would have to be converted to `'thing$HOME'`.

The ultimate goal is to *display* correct bash commands to humans, turning something like `['ls', '-l', 'Filename"with\'crazy$chars']` into `ls -l 'Filename'with'\''crazy$chars'`.

Comment: The shell already does this with its `%q` formatting string for `printf`, e.g. `printf -v quoted '%q' "$somevalue"` to quote the value in `$somevalue` and write it to the variable `quoted`.

Comment: Is that Python? If so, there's [`shlex.quote()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shlex.html#shlex.quote)

Comment: As @Kusalananda said, use `printf '%q'`.  But, IME what you're doing is often a sign that you're [trying to solve the wrong problem](https://xyproblem.info/), trying to "work around" the fact that pathnames can contain **ANY** character except NUL instead of just using NUL as the separator.  Most "standard" utilities these days have a `-z` or `-0` or similar option for handling NUL-separated data.  Also, you shouldn't use scalar string variables to hold entire command-lines - shells like bash, ksh, and zsh have arrays which allow you to store each argument in a separate element.